# I need to add the KEY_TEST integer to this database. I keep getting errors. Can anyone figure this one out

Tags: android, sqlite

Can anyone alter this code to include one integer variable. Not including the database version integer of course. :)

package T2T.Game;

import android.content.ContentValues;

import android.content.Context;

import android.database.Cursor;

import android.database.SQLException;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseUtil {

```
 private static final String TAG = "DatabaseUtil";  



 /**  

  * Database Name  

  */ 

 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "t2tvariables_database";  



 /**  

  * Database Version  

  */ 

 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  



 /**  

  * Table Name  

  */ 

 private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tb_variable";  



 /**  

  * Table columns  

  */ 

 public static final String KEY_VARIABLE = "variable";  

 public static final String KEY_VALUE = "grade";  

 public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";  


 /**  

  * Database creation sql statement  

  */ 

 private static final String CREATE_VARIABLE_TABLE =  

     "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 

     + KEY_VARIABLE +" text not null, " + KEY_VALUE + " text not null);";  



 /**  

  * Context  

  */ 

 private final Context mCtx;  



 private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;  

 private SQLiteDatabase mDb;  



 /**  

  * Inner private class. Database Helper class for creating and updating database.  

  */ 

 private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {  
     DatabaseHelper(Context context) {  

         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  

     }  

     /**  

      * onCreate method is called for the 1st time when database doesn't exists.  

      */ 

     @Override 

     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {  

         Log.i(TAG, "Creating DataBase: " + CREATE_VARIABLE_TABLE);  

         db.execSQL(CREATE_VARIABLE_TABLE);  

     }  

     /**  

      * onUpgrade method is called when database version changes.  

      */ 

     @Override 

     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  

         Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " 

                 + newVersion);  

     }  

 }  



 /**  

  * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be  

  * opened/created  

  *  

  * @param ctx the Context within which to work  

  */ 

 public DatabaseUtil(Context ctx) {  

     this.mCtx = ctx;  

 }  

 /**  

  * This method is used for creating/opening connection  

  * @return instance of DatabaseUtil  

  * @throws SQLException  

  */ 

 public DatabaseUtil open() throws SQLException {  

     mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);  

     mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();  

     return this;  

 }  

 /**  

  * This method is used for closing the connection.  

  */ 

 public void close() {  

     mDbHelper.close();  

 }  



 /**  

  * This method is used to create/insert new record Variable record.  

  * @param variable  

  * @param integer  

  * @return long  

  */ 

 public long createVariable(String variable, String grade ) {  

     ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();  

     initialValues.put(KEY_VARIABLE, variable);  

     initialValues.put(KEY_VALUE, grade);


     return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);  

 }  

 /**  

  * This method will delete Variable record.  

  * @param rowId  

  * @return boolean  

  */ 

 public boolean deleteVariable(long rowId) {  

     return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;  

 }  



 /**  

  * This method will return Cursor holding all the Variable records.  

  * @return Cursor  

  */ 

 public Cursor fetchAllVariables() {  

     return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_VARIABLE,  

             KEY_VALUE}, null, null, null, null, null);  

 }  


 /**  
  * This method will return Cursor holding the specific Variable record.  

  * @param id  

  * @return Cursor  

  * @throws SQLException  

  */ 

 public Cursor fetchVariable(long id) throws SQLException {  

     Cursor mCursor =  

         mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,  

                 KEY_VARIABLE, KEY_VALUE}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null,  

                 null, null, null, null);  

     if (mCursor != null) {  

         mCursor.moveToFirst();  

     }  

     return mCursor;  

 }  



 /**  

  * This method will update Variable record.  

  * @param id  

  * @param variable  

  * @param standard  

  * @return boolean  

  */ 

 public boolean updateVariable(int id, String variable, String standard) {  

     ContentValues args = new ContentValues();  

     args.put(KEY_VARIABLE, variable);  

     args.put(KEY_VALUE, standard);


     return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null) > 0;







 }
```

}

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I get force close on run of APP

Comment: I took this code from an example and edited it. If I had the code that used just one integer besides the database version integer, I would be home free.

Comment: post your logcat so that we can know more about the causes of errors...

Comment: raju, I deleted the code that caused the errors. I have been coding for 2 months. So that means, I am the problem. If you can add an integer to this database utility code, It would save me a lot of time. Or I will continue to hack away at it until I get it to work.

Comment: the code that I posted works for tha strings that are in it. But I need to add an integer variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put any type of value into any type of column in sqlite databse.. except that if you try to put anything other than an integer into an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column you get an error.. so you should not have any problem inserting integers into database... while you are retrieving the values.. you can type cast them into required type.. as integers in this case...

Comment: OK I thought that an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY was only for COLUMN ID's. I shall look into creating another INTEGER PRIMARY KEY and type cast my new INTERGER VARIABLE into that column. Does this sound like a viable solution?

Comment: create a new column as myid(for example) and add integers in that column.. sqlite database doesnt check the type while inserting... so when you are retrieving type cast the string into int.. thats all..

Comment: raju, Thanks for your help. problem solved. Not knowing what I am doing seems to be the key here. I got it to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I accepted it, yesterday but I guess it didnt take. Trying again now

Answer (score 1):

There's no column named `KEY_TEST` in `DATABASE_TABLE`, so it's expected the trying to insert or update that column throws and exception.

Comment: Thats just it. I cant seem to put the correct commands in the entire code to make it work. I took them back out. You can see hash marks in front of the entries that werent enclosed int () or {}

Comment: force close on run of the app

Comment: There are a ton of examples out there, but none of them use integers. They all use strings